# Bring exported Processing-application window to foreground

Tags: processing

How to make the window of an exported application to come foreground? As an example, let us say that I have a text document and browser in active use and the application window is buried behind, how to bring it back to front programmatically. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

A java AWT Frame has a [`toFront()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/awt/Window.html#toFront()) method which does this for you.

You will need to drill down from `PApplet`'s [getSurface()](https://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PApplet.html#getSurface--) to get to the frame first.

A default Processing sketch uses the `JAVA2D` renderer (AWT Surface):

```java
import java.awt.Frame;

import processing.awt.PSurfaceAWT;

Frame frame;

void setup(){
  frameRate(0.5);// test: bring the sketch to front every 2 seconds
  frame = ((PSurfaceAWT.SmoothCanvas)surface.getNative()).getFrame();
  println(frame);
}

void draw(){
  background(random(255));
  frame.toFront();
}
```

(To keep things simple I recommend sticking to the default renderer if possible).